# Why I got the missing package error even though I imported them in Visual Studio Code

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code

I followed/clone this [github repo](https://github.com/linnovate/mean):

Then I open this project in Visual Studio Code. I got this error:

Error:

> 'This syntax requires an imported helper named '__decorate', but module 'tslib' has no exported member '__decorate'.'
>   at: '13,1'
>   source: 'ts'
>
> 'This syntax requires an imported helper named '__metadata', but module 'tslib' has no exported member '__metadata'.'
>   at: '13,1'
>   source: 'ts'
>
> 'Cannot find name 'OnInit'.'
>   at: '27,41'
>   source: 'ts'

[image]

This is the source code:

```
import {
  Component,
  OnInit,
} from '@angular/core';
/**
 * We're loading this component asynchronously
 * We are using some magic with es6-promise-loader that will wrap the module with a Promise
 * see https://github.com/gdi2290/es6-promise-loader for more info
 */

console.log('`Detail` component loaded asynchronously');

@Component({
  selector: 'detail',
  template: `
    <h1>Hello from Detail</h1>
    <span>
      <a [routerLink]=" ['./child-detail'] ">
        Child Detail
      </a>
    </span>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  `,
})
export class DetailComponent implements OnInit {

  public ngOnInit() {
    console.log('hello `Detail` component');
  }

}
```

[image]

P.S. I have reopened Visual Studio Code, but the error is still there.

Comment: https://github.com/AngularClass/angular-starter/issues/1819.  P.S. it is easier to answer questions that include the actual error text, rather than screenshots.

Comment: where are your import statements?

Comment: @Aravind Import statements are at the top of source code that I attached here

Comment: @Claies I attached the actual error text. I did at the link you post, but I still got the this error: Cannot find name 'OnInit'

Comment: are you available in teamviewer?

Comment: @Aravind How do I share my team viewer account with you?

Comment: fb @ aravind2109

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149304/discussion-between-aravind-and-codecontributor).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So as worked using teamviewer you didn't install your `node_modules`

Installing that fixes your issue.

Comment: Thanks debugging the issue using teamviewer. I appreciate. Just do not know why I forgot to do: npm install